# Text property is not updating in the same action

Tags: javafx

I am implementing a menu action that needs to update a Text component at the beginning and at the end of the action.

This is a sample of my code:

```
        MenuItem menuItem = new MenuItem("My Action", new ImageView("path/to/my/icon"));
        menuItem .setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                infoTxt.setText("Beginning");
                try {
                    System.out.println("sleeping...");
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                System.out.println("resuming...");
                infoTxt.setText("Ending");
            }
        });
```

The text of `infoTxt` is updated only at the end of the action with the "Ending" value.

Is it possible to display the "Beginning" value before reaching the end of the action?

Comment: Instead of down votes, is it possible to provide consistent comments of a better approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your `Thread.sleep()` sort of blocks the initial `setText()`. After sleeping the second overwrites it. Move your code that takes time in a separate thread. But be sure to execute the second `setText()` on the ui thread using `runLater()`. Please try this:

```
infoTxt.setText("Beginning");
new Thread(() -> {
    try {
        System.out.println("sleeping...");
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        System.out.println("resuming...");
        Platform.runLater(() -> {
            infoTxt.setText("Ending");
        });
    }
}).start();
```